# Unitary transformation with T invariant subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, orthogonality, unitary-matrices, invariant-subspace

I encountered the following problem and I was wondering whether it is possible to deduce even stronger conclusion that $T = \pm I$ 
This is the problem:

> Let $T: V \to V$ be a linear transformation on a finite dimension inner-product space V and $T^*T = I$
> Prove: If $W$ is $T$ invariant subspace then $W^{\bot}$ is $T$ invariant.

My approach: 
Suppose $W$ is $T$ invariant.
Let $w \in W$ and let $w' \in W^{\bot}$ then $0 = <T(w),w'>  =<T(w),T^*T(w')> = <T(T(w)),T(w')>$ 
Remember that $T^*T = I$ and $T(T(w)) \in W$
Which implies that $T(w') \in W^{\bot}$ therefore $W^{\bot}$ is $T$ invariant.

I was wondering if it's possible to conclude even further that $T = \pm I$ because I know that unitary transformations such as T rotate the whole space and if an arbitrary subspace remains T invariant then it might imply that T is the identity transformation, although I couldn't find a counterexample it seems true to m. Will appreciate any clarifications. Thanks

Comment: The statement is not true. Consider the shift operator $$T(x_1,x_2,\ldots )=(0,x_1,x_2,\ldots ).\quad x\in \ell^2.$$ The subspace $W={\rm Im} T$ is invariant, but $W^\perp$ is not invariant.

Comment: But this transformation is not invertible, it would be weird if this statement not true because it appeared on an exam in my linear algebra course.
$T^*T = I$ implies T is invertible and $T^{-1} = T^*$

Comment: Sorry for misunderstanding, but you haven't mentioned that the space $V$ was finite dimensional.

Comment: @BazyliZuczek It's my bad I will fix it right now

Comment: I don't get it. $T^*T = I$ is equivalent to $T$ being orthogonal and there are orthogonal transformation with non-trivial invariant subspaces. Think for example of a rotation around an axis in ${\bf R}^3$.

Comment: @coudy Yes but I think such transformation will have only 1 invariant subspace (only the axis that stayed in place), this is why I think it implies $T = \pm I$

Comment: It has also the plane that is orthogonal to the axis as a two-dimensional invariant subspace.

Comment: @coudy Ahh okay I get it now, so my intuition wasn't true, thank you !!!

Comment: You are welcome.